# Comparing each geometry of shapefile with all geometries of another shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, features

I want to compare each polygon from one shapefile with all the polygons from another shapefile.
When one polygon is geometrically identical to a polygon on the other shapefile, I want to copy the value of field "code" of the second shapefile to the field "code" of the first shapefile.
I wrote the following code:

```
fc1 = ur'D:\polygons1.shp'
fc2 = ur'D:\polygons2.shp'
fields = ['SHAPE@','code']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc1,fields) as cur1:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2,fields) as cur2:
        for row1 in cur1:
            for row2 in cur2:
                row1[1] = row2[1] if(row1[0]==row2[0]) else ''
            cur1.updateRow(row1)
```

When I run the above code, the values from "code" are not copied plus there are no errors.
Any ideas?

Comment: The object equivalence test will always fail. You need to use a geometry comparison operator. If you do a spatial search of `fc2`, your program won't be `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Have you considered using a [spatial join](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm)?

Comment: @Andy I did use. I just wondering why the above code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As commented you cant compare geometries (SHAPE@) using equal to operator (==), you need a geometry comparison. Use the [equals](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polygon.htm) method:

> Indicates if the base and comparison geometries are of the same shape
>   type and define the same set of points in the plane.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb' #Change
fc1 = 'polygons1' #Change
fc2 = 'Polygons2' #Change
fields = ['SHAPE@','code'] #Change

fc2_records = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2,fields)]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc1,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for record in fc2_records:
            if row[0].equals(record[0]):
                row[1]=record[1]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(If you have large datasets there will be faster ways. You could try merging the feature classes, sort by id and delete duplicates on shape field. Or do a select by location to find overlapping features and then pass these to the cursors.)

Comment: Probably ought to test for objectid1 != objectid2, but that means adding id columns to the fields list

Comment: Equality is not what I want to compare, Identicality is the one I want.  @Vince OIDs between the two shapefiles are completely irrelevant.

Comment: Equals method will return true for identical geometries

Comment: Doh. The OID2>OID1 test is for two queries on a single source.